# partial derivative of $\arctan ( \frac{x+y}{1+xy})$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

partial derivative of $\arctan ( \frac{x+y}{1+xy})$

I am lost in finding the partial derivatives of the function.

I started with the formula $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)}$. But it gets really complicated. Is there an easier way to calculate?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: it would be so much nicer to find the partial derivative of $\arctan\left(\frac{x-y}{1+xy}\right)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so formidable as it looks at beginning. First derivative for $arctan$ is of form $ \frac{1}{1+Q^2} $, next apply Chain rule with Quotient Rule for given fraction,  resulting in ( with respect to x,y ).

Else you can also proceed thus in two steps either with respect to  $x$ or for $y$:

$$ \partial \; tan ^{-1}\frac{u}{v} = \frac{v \;\partial  u - u \;\partial  v }{u^2+v^2}  $$

$$\dfrac{(1-y^2),(1-x^2)}   { (1+ x y)^2 +(x+y)^2 }   $$

---

Comment: Shall indicate steps if you could not get it by yourself so far.